# What does this bash command do?

Tags: bash

I accidentally typed the following. What does it do?

```
gulp lint &7 gulp test
```

I intended to type `&&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it executes the first command in the background:

```
gulp link &
```

Meanwhile tries to execute

```
7 gulp test
```

which should tell yu the command 7 cannot be found